# WebAudio MediaElementSourceNode in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, web-audio-api

I am trying to create a simple WebAudio Player using MediaElementSourceNodes. On Google Chrome works as intended, but in Firefox it plays fine the first time, but when i try to restart it, it doesn't produce any sound (no errors logged). One solution is to create new source for the audio element where it works on Firefox, but then on Chrome it gives me 
`Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to execute 'createMediaElementSource' on 'AudioContext': HTMLMediaElement already connected previously to a different MediaElementSourceNode.` Another solution is to create new Audio element and it works on all browsers, but then it redownloads the mp3 file and this is not ideal because I try to use it more than twice. Can you explain this behaviour and a possible solution? https://jsfiddle.net/0gw86dzn/ (I am using Firefox Developer Edition 48.0a2 (2016-05-16))

```
<html>
    <body>
        <input type="button" value="stop" id="stop">
        <input type="button" value="play" id="play">
        <script>
            var context = new AudioContext();

            var audio = new Audio("test.mp3");
            audio.controls = true;

            var source = context.createMediaElementSource(audio);
            source.connect(context.destination);

            var play = document.getElementById('play')
            play.onclick = function () {
              //source = context.createMediaElementSource(audio); // firefox is happy, but chrome bugs.

              //audio = new Audio("test.mp3"); //works, but it redownloads the audio.

              audio.play();
            }

            var stop = document.getElementById('stop');
            stop.onclick = function () {
              audio.pause();
              audio.currentTime = 0;
            }
      </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

'Disconnect' your destination source in your stop method, then re 'connect' your destination source in your play method. That should take care of your issue.